# Are these metamers, if not why?

Tags: isomers

Please tell me if these are metamers ie **Metamerism:** In Chemistry the type of isomerism in which chemical compounds have identical proportions of the same elements and the same molecular weight, but have radicals differing in type or position, with resulting differences in chemical properties.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The term **metamer** isn't terminology that is widely used today, and indeed doesn't appear in the IUPAC Gold Book (the International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry publishes guidelines for standardised nomenclature in chemistry and is widely adopted).

The description you're looking for is **structural isomerism**, with the compounds you show being examples of **positional isomers** (isomers which differ by the position of the functional groups, for instance in this case the relative positions of the methyl and methoxy moieties).

Comment: Thank you,but can you still answer it while referring to metamerism.

Comment: Well, yes, they are metamers...you're just unlikely to hear them referred to as such.